# Outputing 2 object arrays in foreach cycle

Tags: php, arrays, object, joomla, foreach

below is example how mine arrays do look, i want them combine so i can output both title, votes and ratings in one line.

```
foreach ($items->items as $item) {
echo $item->title;

foreach ($results->resx as $res) {
echo $res->votes;
echo $res->ratings;
}
```

I'd like to have this, but i know this isn't right.

```
foreach ($items as $item) ($results as $res) {
echo $res->votes;
echo $res->ratings;
echo $item->title;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**array_merge()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for that, like so:

```
foreach (array_merge($results, $items) as $item) {
   echo isset($item->title) ? $item->title : $item->votes .'<br>'. $item->ratings;
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Changed how to print values as the objects from merged array can only have one of the two groups of properties.

**UPDATE 2**:
After some OP's notes that made more clear what his scenario is, and now given the assumption that both `$results` and `$items` arrays have the same number of elements, an update solution is as follows:

```
while ((list(, $it) = each($items)) && (list(, $rs) = each($results))) {
    echo $it->title;
    echo $rs->votes;
    echo $rs->ratings . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I use in this code $i = 0; $i++ variable, so i actually need it to start from 0 when two properties are printed. Now I used $i = -4; but in other cases it probably wont work.

Comment: This is not working as supposed. I can't print both properties in 1 row.

Comment: Both arrays are being printed ir foreach cycle separately, e.g in first row $itemx->voting is empty, but $itemx->title is printed. empty. E.g
title
title
title
title
results
results
..
etc..
I want this:
Item, Results
Item, Results

Comment: Use then:  echo empty($item->title) ? $item->votes .'<br>'. $item->ratings : $item->title;

Comment: It still prints results like: title title title title, ratings ratings etc.
But i want-> title, ratings. title, ratings. :/

Comment: Ok, now it's more clear to me what you want, see my updated answer.